# Group the data of a table based on the date and build the multicolumns table for values in MYsql

Tags: mysql, sql

I was really stuck in this SQL program for more than a week.
I have a table that has three columns, one column shows the ids, one shows the date, and one shows the temperature.  Here is the code for the table:

```
Create table  temperature (id int, date varchar(255), temperature float(2, 1));

 insert into temperature (id, date, temperature) values ('1', '2012-01-01 6:00:00',  '8.9');
 insert into temperature (id, date,  temperature) values ('1', '2012-01-01 6:15:00',  '8.5');
 insert into temperature (id, date,  temperature) values ('1', '2012-01-01 6:30:00',  '6.2');
 insert into temperature (id, date,  temperature) values ('1', '2012-01-01 6:45:00',  '8.6');
 insert into temperature(id, date,  temperature) values ('3', '2012-01-02 6:00:00',  '9.1');
 insert into temperature (id, date,  temperature) values ('3', '2012-01-01 6:15:00',  '8.9');
 insert into temperature (id, date,  temperature) values ('4', '2012-01-01 6:00:00',  '8.5');
 insert into temperature (id, date,  temperature) values ('4', '2012-01-01 6:15:00',  '6.2');
 insert into temperature (id, date,  temperature) values ('4', '2012-01-01 6:30:00',  '8.6');
 insert into temperature (id, date,  temperature) values ('2', '2012-01-01 6:00:00',  '9.1');
 SELECT * FROM temperature;
```

And here is the figure of table:

[image]

Each row has a very specific time. I want to show the temperature of each id and each time slot in one column.

For example, for id=1, we have four temperatures. Then we have 4 value and put them in order in the val1-val4.  for id=3, we have two day with one numbers, for each day we consider one list, and id=4 we have three numbers in one day and for id=2 we have only one number for one day.

The maximum length of the values is 4 (in my real application is 96).

Finally, I want this table (there is a typo in the figure, val2 for the second id=3 should be 8.9):

[image]

I have used the `group_concat`, however, it saves them as a string. Besides I am using `date_format(from_unixtime(date), '%Y-%m-%d')`To change the date to YYYY-MM-DD. The code I am using is

```
   SELECT id, 
          date_format(from_unixtime(date), '%Y-%d-%m') as date, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(value) as Value group by id, date
    FROM temperature;
```

Note: In my real database, the maximum length of the value is 96 and I have more then 10 Million rows,  and it is not efficient to use the `CASE` and `WHEN`.

Comment: Could you post expected result as well

Comment: Thanks @ergestbasha for reminds me. I've just put the table that I want.

Answer (score 1):

If your `MySQL` version supports windows function you could use:

```
with cte as (
select id, date, temperature,row_number() over(partition by id order by `date`) rownum
from temperature
) 
select id,date(`date`),max(case when rownum=1 then cte.temperature else null end) as val1,
                       max(case when rownum=2 then cte.temperature else null end) as val2,
                       max(case when rownum=3 then cte.temperature else null end) as val3,
                       max(case when rownum=4 then cte.temperature else null end) as val4
from cte
group by id,date(`date`);
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=caf75e47a7f4c5262e3823ab14a37248)

Comment: Thanks. This works for a small example, but in my real database, I have 96 time step and over than 10 Million rows. And this is not efficient for my real case.

Comment: @Yellowman that is another problem that isn't related to the original question. If you have performance issue you could ask another question. Keep in mind that date function will not use index if it is one